# The Return value is not true in arraylist of android App

Tags: java, android, arraylist, return

This function returns two objects `TMBase.customer@40fb1588`, `TMBase.customer@40fb1ad8`, but I need to return these values `emy`, `samera`. I need to know what is the problem?

```
public ArrayList<TMBase.Customer> GetWorkerNameOfCustomerByID( int LineID)
{    
    ArrayList<TMBase.Customer> CustomerArr = new ArrayList<TMBase.Customer>();
    connecttodatabase qq = new connecttodatabase();
    qq.dbconnect();
    if (qq.con != null) 
    {
        String result = "";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {           
            CallableStatement cstmt = null;
            Statement st = qq.con.createStatement();
            cstmt = qq.con.prepareCall("{CALL GetWorkerNameOfCustomerByID(?)}");

            cstmt.setInt(1, LineID);
            rs = cstmt.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                TMBase.Customer CustomerObj=new TMBase.Customer();
                CustomerObj.setWorkerName(rs.getString("WorkerName"));   
                CustomerArr.add(CustomerObj);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        qq.closeConnection();
    }
    return CustomerArr;
}
```

**Customer class:**

```
package TMBase;

public class Customer {
    private int ID;
    private int LineId; 
    private int WorkerId; 
    private Timestamp DateSubscribe; 
    private String WorkerName;

    public int getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public int setID(int ID){
        return this.ID = ID;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    public int getLineId() {
        return this.LineId;
    }

    public int setLineId(int LineId){
        return this.LineId = LineId;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    public int getWorkerId() {
        return this.WorkerId;
    }

    public int setWorkerId(int WorkerId){
        return this.WorkerId = WorkerId;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    public Timestamp getDateSubscribe() {
        return this.DateSubscribe;`enter code here`
    }

    public Timestamp setDateSubscribe(Timestamp DateSubscribe){
        return this.DateSubscribe = DateSubscribe;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String getWorkerName() {
        return this.WorkerName;
    }

    public String setWorkerName(String WorkerName){
        return this.WorkerName = WorkerName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override the `toString()` method of your `Customer` object.

I'm assuming you are using an `ArrayAdapter` to display these in your `ListView`, which calls `toString()` on each item in the dataset to display on the screen.

By overriding `toString()`, you can return whatever data you want to be displayed in the `ListView` for example:

```
public String toString(){
    return getWorkerName();
}
```